# leveling replacement tile

Tags: flooring, tile, tiling

I have just complete an area of tile where 99% of tile is great, but I have a tile with a lippage that bother me. I'm willing to pull up the tile and replace it but is there a way to level it with the rest of the tile without pulling the entire floor out?

Comment: Is it high or low?  Low is usually easier, since high usually means shaving the floor or tile, unless something is holding tile up.  Is just one edge different or the whole tile?

Comment: the one tile is higher on one side. I suspect the subfloor is uneven but difficult to fix that now I'm assuming.

Comment: A wooden subfloor should not be too hard to reduce in height, not easy though.  Might be lucky and find something dropped between tile and floor, you missed.  Talking about 1/16, 1/8 difference?

Comment: Around 1/16 difference but because that is the only side not leveled, feels obvious.

Comment: Not the fastest but a power sander with low grit number should knock it it down and keep it level and flat.  Edges by the other tiles might need to be done with a sharp chisel.

Comment: sanding the tile down would lower durability would it not? I was hoping there would be a leveler that can push it down harder.

Comment: You don't fix tile level problems from the top. ***Is*** this ceramic tile, vinyl "tile" or something else...? *Pushing down harder* only works when the mortar is still flowable.

Comment: I did mean to sand the wood floor, not the tile.  A leveler would increase the height.

Answer (score 1):

If you pop the tile out (may be possible depending how long it's been in place, and the nature of your mortar) or break it out if it won't pop, and chisel the mortar out below it until the replacement tile will set below the other tiles, then add just enough mortar to bring it up to level, you can avoid redoing the whole floor. Depending on the problem area, you might want to remove 9 tiles (the problem and all tiles immediately around it) to allow a proper fix.

*That's assuming ceramic tile, I guess your question really doesn't say.*

Comment: porcelain tiles. There are six connecting tiles. I'm afraid that if I start tear out the 6 tiles the ones on the edge would start unlevel because I can't slide leveler below the ones that don't get tear out. Then it becomes a project of just redoing it all the floors.